# c# visual studio Scrolling game boss level give boss a healthbar

Tags: c#

making a scrolling game and breaking it into smaller pieces till I solve the new addition and then I add it to the game. I figured out how to create a healthbar for the player so when he gets hit by the enemies it shows the bars level diminishing. I can't seem to make the reverse for the enemy boss. Right now I have a progress bar for the player called healthbar set for 100% and decreases by 10 every time the player is hit. I also have a progressbar for the boss called bosshealth which is also set at 100% and also decreases by 10 every time he is hit. Right now when the boss hits the player with his laser the player takes damage but when the player shoots the boss, he doesn't take any damage.

```
void HitorMiss()
{
    if(Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(powerarmour.Bounds) || Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(e1laser.Bounds))
    {
        if (healthbar.Value <= 0)
        {
            healthbar.Value = 100;
        }
        else if (healthbar.Value == 0)
            Dead();
        else
            healthbar.Value -= 10;
    }
    else if(powerarmour.Bounds.IntersectsWith(shoot.Bounds))
    {
        if (bosshealth.Value <= 0)
        {
            bosshealth.Value = 100;
        }
        else if (bosshealth.Value == 0)
        {
            //code to make boss explode and then disappear
        }
        else
            bosshealth.Value -= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug to see if it ever goes into the *else if(powerarmour.Bounds.IntersectsWith(shoot.Bounds))* block? Maybe the collision just isn't as expected. Also, are you using Unity or some library to do this? Please tag it.

Answer (score -1):

that is a pretty confusing piece of code - but i liked the name of the method haha.

i would recomend doing something like:

```
  void HitorMiss(){
if(Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(powerarmour.Bounds) || Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(e1laser.Bounds))
{
    healthbar.Value = 100;
    if (healthbar.Value == 0) Dead();
    else healthbar.Value -= 10;
}
 if(powerarmour.Bounds.IntersectsWith(shoot.Bounds))
{
    bosshealth.Value = 100; 

    if (bosshealth.Value == 0) BossDead();


    else bosshealth.Value -= 10; 
}}
```

but i strongly recomend you to set the hp and the death logic outside of the hit method.

Comment: Why `healthbar.Value = 100`? It will reset the health to 100 every time it hits, no?

Comment: Code is not correctly indented. Also, how does this answer solve the problem? *Right now when the boss hits the player with his laser the player takes damage but when the player shoots the boss, he doesn't take any damage.* The problem is his code isn't working for the latter.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it only takes away life from the player and not the boss.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is have a healthbar for the player and for the boss so it takes more than one hit to kill the boss